# Non-trivial PCP characterizations of complexity classes beyond ELEMENTARY?

Tags: complexity-classes, pcp, program-verification

There are interesting results of the form $PCP[a(n), b(n)] = \texttt{SOMECLASS(n)}$ for multiple classes in the exponential hierarchy: the most famous one is probably $PCP[O(log(n)), O(1)] = NP$.

Are there similar theorems for larger complexity classes, such as [PR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PR_(complexity)), [$F_\omega$](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.5686.pdf), and other beyond ELEMENTARY?  Do these theorems cover the [complexity classes](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9775/class-of-functions-computable-by-coq) implied by proof assistants that only accept total functions?